# google or tools VRPTW with service times

Tags: python, or-tools, vehicle-routing

I'm looking for a solution for VRPTW using google or- tools with vehicle working hours.

given any vehicle has it's own working hours.
example:
Vehicle A: 9am to 3pm
Vehicle B: 8am to 4pm

I came up with below code

```
# times in seconds
data['working_time'] = [
  (0, 600), 
  (0, 32400), 
  (0, 36000)
]


# add working times for each vehicle
    for vehicle in range(duration_manager.GetNumberOfVehicles()):
        start_index = duration_routing.Start(vehicle)
        end_index = duration_routing.End(vehicle)

        duration_dimension.CumulVar(start_index).SetRange(
            data['working_time'][vehicle][0], data['working_time'][vehicle][1])
        duration_dimension.CumulVar(end_index).SetRange(
            data['working_time'][vehicle][0], data['working_time'][vehicle][1])

        duration_routing.solver().Add(duration_dimension.CumulVar(end_index) - duration_dimension.CumulVar(start_index) <= duration_dimension.CumulVar(end_index))
```

this works fine but if I changed

```
data['working_time'] = [
  (0, 600), 
  (0, 32400), 
  (3600, 36000) # start time change!!!
]
```

I'm getting

```
Exception: CP Solver fail
```

Please help

Comment: when invoking AddDimensionWithVehicleCapacity, use fix_start_cumul_to_zero=False (it's the 4th parameter). also you can use the vehicle_capacities parameter to set the end of shift values (3rd parameter). as for the shift start, I advice you to use SetMin instead of SetRange

Comment: I need to assign different working times for each vehicle. can I do that with your suggestion?

Comment: yes, vehicle_capacities is an array with the same length as the number of vehicles.